# how does one determine programmatically in C# if IPv6 is supported?

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# programming getting the loopback IP of the server. how can I determine programmatically in C# that if IPv6 is supported?

Answer (score 5):

You can check it by accessing this property

```
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.OSSupportsIPv6;
```

Info http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.sockets.socket.ossupportsipv6(v=vs.110).aspx